# Update Custom Metadata

Tags: metadata, workbench, custom-metadata

I am trying to update some custom meta records. There are current 4384 records in the system. And update give me an error of "Collection size 4,384 exceeds maximum size of 1,000." This happens even if I try to upload fewer than 1000 records.

I tried to delete them from the Workbench and just start over. But I get an error that I have insufficient access rights on object Id.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a Visualforce page for this. Are you using the "Custom Metadata Uploader" by chance?

Comment: Hi sfdcfox., Yes I am using the Custom Metadata Uploader.